# ValueError. save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'filiere'

Tags: django, forms

When validating my form I get an error that says:
valueError, save () prohibited to prevent data. loss die to unsaved related object 'filiere'
Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
   fil = Filiere(nom_filiere=filiere)
   niv = Niveau.objects.create(niveau=niveau, filiere=fil)
```

I don't want to create or save fil(fil.save()) because "filiere" already exists in the database, I just want make the link between "niveau" and "filiere"

Comment: Not a lot of code to work with, but try to get the actual object i.e. Filiere.objects.get(nom_filiere=filiere).

Comment: Okay.it's work.

Answer (score 3):

Get the actual object before you save it as the value:

```
fil = Filiere.objects.get(nom_filiere=filiere) // retrieve the object
niv = Niveau.objects.create(niveau=niveau, filiere=fil) // then save
```